# react-intl - Type '(string | MessageFormatElement)' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, react-intl

I am using react-intl for i18n in react with TS. I am getting my translated string using the hook

```
const intl = useIntl();
intl.messages['my.key']
```

However, TS throws an error

```
Type '(string | MessageFormatElement)' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How to instruct react-intl to return me string?

Comment: Use `formatMessage({id: 'my.key'})`

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer. If you would post it as answer, then you could bump up your reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to access the internals of the message, you can use the useful `formatMessage` function to convert the message to a string given the `ID`:

```
const {formatMessage} = useIntl();
console.log(formatMessage({id: 'my.key'});
```